# Why The up button has been added in all activities while i enabled it only in one activity?

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-appcompat

I followed the Google documentation for adding the up button , here is the link `https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral?utm_source=udacity&utm_medium=course&utm_campaign=android_basics` , so first i modified my manifest file so it looks like :

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--
 Copyright (C) 2016 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at
}});}}
          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.

-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.miwok">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".PhrasesActivity"
            android:label="@string/category_phrases"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity" />
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity" />/>

        <activity android:name=".NumbersActivity"
            android:label="@string/category_numbers"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity" />
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity" />/>

        <activity android:name=".FamilyActivity"
            android:label="@string/category_family"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity" />
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ColorsActivity"
            android:label="@string/category_colors"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity" />
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity" />/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

As , you can see i have 4 child activities , after that randomly I've chosen the `NumbersActivity` to test the up button , by adding this line of code in it's java file :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

What i couldn't understand is why the up button has been being enabled in all other child activities without updating theirs java file ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These statements in the manifest:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity" />

android:parentActivityName="com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity"
```

makes the up button available to all child activities in order to return to the parent activity.

Note: this way of returning back to the parent activity, always recreates the parent activity and this may not be what you want. 
So to avoid the recreation of the parent activity add in the manifest this line for MainActivity:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Comment: i removed the line of code   getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); and it still works so why they mentionned that in the documentation ??

Comment: It is mentioned, but this is not the recommended way. Give me a minute to edit my answer.

Comment: @Abdell00 If you found the answer you were looking for, accept this answer

Comment: First of all thanks , then i've accepted the answer however i still have one question  the line android:launchMode="singleTop" does it provide a return to the mainActivity or just the previous activity ?

Comment: This line just prevents the recreation of the parent activity, so the onCreate() of the parent activity is not triggered again.